# Mathematical notation in algorithms

Tags: algorithm, math, notation

I am currently reading the [Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/), but my mathematical notation has become a little rusty.

What does

[image: "\left( a \ b \right)" LaTeX]

mean?

Comment: A helpful link for mathematical formulas: http://texify.com

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)? (also, see [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination))

Comment: Binomial coefficient is the second one I was going to suggest, but I couldn't remember what it was. I think it's time for me to brush up on my discrete math.

Comment: Not to be confused with the Legendre Symbol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol

Answer (score 10):

It means "n choose k", or in this case, "a choose b". It is a shorthand for the formula a!/(b!((a-b)!)).

Sorry for the many parenthesis, just didn't want amibuity. ! means factorial, 5! = 5*4*3*2*1, etc.

It is used for binomial expansion, and Pascal's Triangle.

Answer (score 4):

[Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) is the first thing that comes to mind...but without context, there are probably other meanings for the same notation.

Answer (score 3):

[Combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).